# use of moved value: `response` value used here after move for types not implementing the Copy trait

Tags: rust, ownership

I have this code which is throwing the following error: `use of moved value: response value used here after move`.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use reqwest::Response;
use serde_json::json;

async fn error_example() -> (Response, String) {
    let execute_url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";

    let client = reqwest::Client::new();

    let response = client.post(execute_url).send().await.unwrap();

    let response_body = response.text().await.unwrap();
    let response_body: HashMap<String, String> = serde_json::from_str(&response_body).unwrap();
    let execution_id = response_body.get("userId").unwrap();

    return (response, execution_id.clone()); // use of moved value: `response` value used here after move
}
```

The error come from the response_body variable using the response variable and taking ownership of it. I wanted to clone the response, or wrap the extraction of the key (execution_id) in a function and passing a ref of the `response` but none worked.

I should have the Clone or Copy trait implemented but I can't implement it for struct not defined within the crate. So I don't know how to handle this case.

How can I get rid of the error ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Reqwest's `Response` type does not really contain the response body. It's basically an open network socket plus the state needed to accept the data. When you call `text`, it builds a `String` straight from the socket. If you wanted to call `text` again, you'd need to resend the request, since neither `Response` nor the socket store this data.

So if you want to return the whole request body, you can return the string that was just created.

```rs
let response_body = response.text().await.unwrap();
let response_map: HashMap<String, String> = serde_json::from_str(&response_body).unwrap();
let execution_id = response_map.get("userId").unwrap().clone();

(response_body, execution_id)
```

Or you could return the headers, or status code, or whatever else you need. Reqwest doesn't have a type to represent a spent response, but you could make your own.

---

Another thing is that deserializing the entire response is not necessary. You can make a struct for just the field you need, which means you only need to allocate one `String`, and you don't need to clone it.

```rs
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct OnlyUserId {
    user_id: String
}

let only_user_id: OnlyUserId = serde_json::from_str(&response_body).unwrap();
let execution_id = only_user_id.user_id;

(response_body, execution_id)
```

Comment: @Cizia incidentally you can see the information in the method signature: [`Response::text`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.text) takes `self`, so it consumes the request object. So most functions which return the body's content, with the exception of [`Response::chunk`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.chunk) which is used to "read out" the response stream as it's received (however as documented once the response stream has been read through this'll return `None`, and other body functions should return no data)

Comment: Also reqwest [has json support](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.json), you should only need to enable the `json` feature (e.g. `cargo add reqwest --features json` or something along those lines), you should not need to deserialize the body by hand.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your answer drewtato. I have to make the query twice to get both the response and and field coming from the response ? The first code snippet  you provided basically is the same as mine (or I don't understand the difference).

Because I need the response to check the statut later and the user_id to query the good user again later.

Comment: Thanks Masklinn for the additionnal help, very helpful I didn't know that

Comment: Actually I don't need the response itself, I just need the status so I can store the status prior to calling .text(), and I can return the status + execution_id instead of the response + execution_id. 

Problem solved thank you both of you guys !